# Checking Listbox items before inserting it into the MS Access database

Tags: c#

How to avoid duplicate data in my MS Access database?

How can I check the items in the listbox1 if it already present in my MS Access database and if it exists, then proceed to the next listbox1 item and check that item already exists.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into ASD (SerialNumber) values (@SerialNumber)", con);

        var parameter3 = new OleDbParameter("@SerialNumber", OleDbType.LongVarChar);
        parameter3.Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter3);  
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < listBox1.Items.Count; a++)
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter da;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from ASD where SerialNumber = '"+listBox1.Text+"'", con);
                da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show( "Serial Number Already Inserted!");
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {                          
                        cmd.Parameters["@SerialNumber"].Value = listBox1.Items[i];                       
                    }

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Item Added");
                }              
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x + "");
        }
}
```

Comment: For a moment forget about your listbox. How do you check if an item is already in your data table?

Comment: @PepitoSh  ill use if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
am i right sir?

Comment: Why does some of your code use `listBox1.Text` and some use `listBox1.Items[i]`? What is the difference between them?

Comment: @mjwills are they same?
i use listBox1.Text because i want to check the text in the listBox if its in database
and i use listBox1.Items[i] to loop  and insert all text i added to the listBox1

Comment: if you use use if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) you only know if there are items in your table.

Comment: @PepitoSh what would be the right code sir? please i really need your help.
the code in "else statement" is running well but the code in "if" statement is not working as what i want to.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a good idea to separate database operations from business logic and presentation. Deal with issues one by one.

To check if you have an item in your table you have a few options.

SQL side with fault: Make a unique index on the SerialNumber column. Whenever you try to add a new record with an existing SerialNumber value the insert will fail and you get an error message. I do not recommend this approach.

SQL side with query: before you try to insert a new value run a query against the database if this SerialNumber value is already in the table. I do not recommend this one as it translates to a lot of SQL queries.

Code side: Get a complete list of SerialNumber values in memory with a single SQL query. Check against this list if the next value is already in the list. 
If the number of records in not too high, I would do this way.

If the number of records is high I would create a stored procedure and call it with a complete list of new records. This SP would insert new records if can and would return the records failed.